# Python how to Enumerate k-mers Lexicographically

Tags: python, permutation, bioinformatics

I have trouble doing this exercise, I want to get from a string of k letters and a number, a combination of all permutations of that number ordered lexicographically.
This is my code:

```
string = 'A C G T'
n = int(2)
lista = []
for element in string:
    if element != ' ':
    lista.append(element)
perm = combinations_with_replacement(lista,n)
for i in list(perm):
    print(i)
```

This is my output:
('A', 'A')
('A', 'C')
('A', 'G')
('A', 'T')
('C', 'C')
('C', 'G')
('C', 'T')
('G', 'G')
('G', 'T')
('T', 'T')
And it's not bad but I have GT and not TG, AG but not GA, and i don't know how to include those

Ty in advance, really apreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead:

```
from itertools import product

pool = "A C G T".split()
n = 2

[*map("".join, product(pool, repeat=n))]

['AA', 'AC', 'AG', 'AT', 
 'CA', 'CC', 'CG', 'CT', 
 'GA', 'GC', 'GG', 'GT', 
 'TA', 'TC', 'TG', 'TT']
```

Comment: Wow, ty so much, this is what I needed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> s = "ACGT"
>>> n = 2
>>> l = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(s, n))
>>> l
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('A', 'T'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'G'), ('C', 'T'), ('G', 'G'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'T')]
```

If you want both "AG" and "GA", for example, you need to use [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```py
>>> l = list(itertools.permutations(s, n))
>>> l
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('A', 'T'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'G'), ('C', 'T'), ('G', 'A'), ('G', 'C'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'A'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'G')]
```

To have every single combination with also XX (for every X in your original pool of letters), you need to use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```py
>>> l = list(itertools.product(s, repeat=n))
>>> l
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('A', 'T'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'G'), ('C', 'T'), ('G', 'A'), ('G', 'C'), ('G', 'G'), ('G', 'T'), ('T', 'A'), ('T', 'C'), ('T', 'G'), ('T', 'T')]
```

Comment: Check answer carefully, "TG" is an output of `permutations`.

Comment: But then AA isn't.

Comment: Ty, i was a bit lost at first